# How to serialize groups of a user with Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get users groups with Django REST framework, but only what I got is empty field named "groups".

This is my UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'groups')
```

any ideas how to get users groups data?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to specify that it's a nested relationships:

```python
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'groups',)
```

Check documentation for more information : [Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: you forgot to add a comma after 'name' in GroupSerializer. It should be: fields = ('name', )

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: And you need add this import `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group`

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    groups = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name',
     )  
 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'groups',)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider including an explanation of your code in your answer.